# vector subspace of all polynomials with complex coefficients so that $p(i)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to prove that the set of all polynomials with complex coefficients so that $p(i)=0$ is a vector supspace

$p(i)=\lambda_1 i^2+\lambda_2i+\lambda=0 $

Comment: i don't know what to try i am looking for a "starting direction"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because:

- the null polynomial belongs to your set;
- if $p_1(i)=0$ and $p_2(i)=0$, then $(p_1+p_2)(i)=0$;
- if $p(i)=0$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb C$, then $\lambda p(i)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

What are the axioms of a vector subspace?

1. Addition among elements must commute. Trivial
2. Multiplication from the scalar field (complex numbers) must satisfy left and right distributive properties. Trivial
3. If p and q are in the set, $ap+bq$ must also be in the set (a, b are complex numbers). Is this true?

If $p(i)=0$ and q(i)=0, then $ap(i)+bq(i)$ = $a\cdot0+b\cdot0=0$ so $ap+bq$ is in the set.

And also the zero polynomial is in the set (which actually follows from 3).

And there's your proof. Notice that the real step was to show that linear combinations of elements stay in the space, which is a fundamental property of vector spaces.

There is also something very special about your requirement that $p(i)=0$. For example, $\{p(z) \in \mathbb{C} [z] \mid p(i)=1\}$ would not give a vector subspace because it's not true that $a\cdot p(i) + b \cdot q(i) = a+b = 1$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

Define the operator $E$ as $Ep = p(i)$. It is straightforward to check
that $E$ is a linear operator.

Then $\{ p | p(i) = 0 \} = \ker E$. Since the kernel is a linear subspace you are finished.